# @Qualifier on the custom annotation

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I was just going through this below video on proxy mechanism.

refer time : 17:45 to 18:30

I also started reading about annotations and reflection recently. So Incase you would prefer to understand the problem here itself, the vide says :

Lets say we have an interface :

```
public interface IPrimeService {

 boolean isPrime (int input);

}

public classPrimeService implements IPrimeService {

@Override
public boolean isPrime (int inp){
    // some logic
  }
}


public classPrimeServiceWithCache implements IPrimeService {

@Override
public boolean isPrime (int inp){
    // some logic
  }
}
```

Now, out of multiple ways to decide on how to get the desired implementation at runtime when doing something like :

```
@Autowired
IPrimeService primeService;
```

one of the mechanism mentioned is - create a custom notification like :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
@Inherited
public @interface WithCache{
}
```

and further put it on one of the implementation like :

```
@WithCache
public classPrimeServiceWithCache implements IPrimeService {

@Override
public boolean isPrime (int inp){
    // some logic
  }
}
```

and further use it like :

```
@WithCache
IPrimeService primeService;
```

so now it will always pick the implementation withCache class implementation.

Question :

my understanding was the we need to provide some identifier with the qualifier annotation, something like :

```
@Qualifier("WithCache")
```

since nothing was used here then how does it understands that which implementation to be picked ?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. There is no such requirement. The `@Qualifier` annotation now marks this annotation as a way to qualify, instead of using names.

Comment: but is it not that qualifier needs a name value ? because so far whenever I saw the use of Qualifier, it was always like @Qualifier("someName")

Comment: No it doesn't. And that is because that is using the `@Qualifier` annotation directly on fields or method arguments.